# Tree algorithm in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data and table structure. I am creating MySQL stored procedure to sum all the amount in the leftchild of the parentid, I don't have enough knowledge in stored procedures.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytree` (
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `mytree` (`parentid`, `memberid`, `position`, `amount`) VALUES
    (8, 27, 'R', 0.00),
    (8, 28, 'L', 0.00),
    (24, 26, 'R', 0.00),
    (0, 1, '', 5500.00),
    (24, 25, 'L', 0.00),
    (21, 24, 'L', 500.00),
    (21, 23, 'R', 0.00),
    (18, 20, 'R', 1500.00),
    (18, 19, 'L', 0.00),
    (15, 18, 'R', 2000.00),
    (15, 17, 'L', 0.00),
    (13, 16, 'L', 0.00),
    (13, 15, 'R', 2500.00),
    (12, 14, 'R', 0.00),
    (12, 13, 'L', 3000.00),
    (10, 12, 'R', 3500.00),
    (10, 11, 'L', 0.00),
    (7, 10, 'R', 4000.00),
    (7, 9, 'L', 0.00),
    (5, 8, 'R', 500.00),
    (5, 7, 'L', 4500.00),
    (1, 6, 'R', 0.00),
    (1, 5, 'L', 5500.00),
    (20, 22, 'R', 0.00),
    (20, 21, 'L', 1000.00);
```

Here is my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `count_left_right_amount`(IN `p_memid` INT, OUT `tot_left_amount` DECIMAL(10,2))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
 
DECLARE row_total decimal(10,2);
DECLARE total decimal(10,2);
DECLARE m_left int;
DECLARE run_left int;
DECLARE p_id int;

set total =  0;

select memberid into p_id from mytree where position = 'L' AND parentid = p_memid;




WHILE  p_id != 0 DO

 select amount into row_total from mytree where parentid = p_id 
  GROUP BY parentid;
  
 select memberid into m_left from mytree where parentid = p_id;
 set total = total + row_total;
 set p_id = m_left;
 

END WHILE;


END
```

Example if the parentid is 5, so the leftchild is 7 then go down to his subtree sum it all,so the total amount in the left child is '22500'? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `unclear what you're asking `

Comment: If you want sum all child of parentid 5.. please, read this post: [Tree-Hierarchical query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes)

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.JAVA.net,did you see my data ? it is adjacency structure.7 is the left child of 5,now I want to sum all the amount in the subtree of 7

Comment: I'm expecting to see a recursive call to `count_left_right_amount`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff,how would I do that in stored proc ?